# Maven dependencies for AWS S3 Camel Component

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-camel

I am writing a Camel route where I am trying to use aws-s3 component to write data into an S3 bucket.
I have two questions:

1. [Documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/aws-s3-component.html) suggestions that this component is available since Camel 2.8. However the [maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-aws-s3) only has version 3.0.0
2. I am using Camel version 2.22.0, is there any older version of aws-s3 component available for this version? I have seen some stackoverflow questions where people are using this component with 2.xx version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the bundles are now separated for each aws component from 3.0. Prior to that "camel-aws" included all the aws components including s3.

If you are using a previous camel version(like 2.22), then adding camel-aws to your pom should enable you to use S3 functionalities.